# Jest Mock 3rd party TS module - Getting "module not found" error while mocking

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest, react-testing

I am getting "module not found" error everytime I mock `material-ui-nested-menu-item` module using jest and react-testing-library.

**Versions used**

- jest: 25.5.4
- ts-jest: 25.5.1

Code is similar to following snippet-

**App.ts**

```
import NestedMenuItem from "material-ui-nested-menu-item"

const App = () => {
    // uses NestedMenuItem here 
}
```

**App.test.tsx**

```
jest.mock("material-ui-nested-menu-item", () => {
    return {
        __esModule: true,
        default: () => createElement('div')
    };
})
describe("App component", () => {
    beforeEach(cleanup)

    it("Render component", async () => {
        render(<App />)
    })
})
```

**Error --**

```
Cannot find module 'material-ui-nested-menu-item' from 'App.test.ts'

      4 |
    > 5 | jest.mock("material-ui-nested-menu-item", () => {
        |      ^
      6 |     return {
      7 |         __esModule: true,
      8 |         default: () => createElement('div')
```